How do I disable safe search in Python googlesearch library?
I'm trying to use Python googlesearch library. It works very well, though it seems like the search() function of this library has some filters that prevent it from searching for certain things (18+ for example) which limits its functionality.
So, is there a way I can disable these filters/safe search? And if yes, how?

According to the documentation, safe='off' is the default.  So it seems safe search should be disabled, unless you specifically turn it on.  Can you provide your actual code, and the results, and explain why those results weren't what you expected?

Did you try:
search("Google", safe=None)

?

Thank you! Other people downvoted my question for no reason, but you actually told me the solution!
